# How to view pdf that is stored in google drive in React Native Expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, pdf

In my project I need the user to be able to view PDF file from google drive. But I dont want the user to be force to have google to view it. When I tried to view it using `expo-web-browser`, I got a Toast saying `Could not find any Google accounts, existing application`. This is the code:

```
const viewPdfFromGoogleDrive = async () => {
    const pdfUrl = 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/your_pdf_id/view';
    await WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync(pdfUrl);
};
return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={viewPdfFromGoogleDrive}>
        <Text style={[GlobalStyle.FunctionText]}>Terms & Condition</Text> 
    </TouchableOpacity>
)
```